# Multithreaded support in MPI RMA

Tags: multithreading, mpi

I am trying to figure out what "automatic" support exists for parallelisation/multithreaded support with RMA operations (specifically MPI_Get's) in MPI

With explicit MPI_Send/MPI_Recv pairs of operations, the semantics forces you to handle the parallelisation yourself - even with the non-blocking functions. But with RMA, this is not obvious.

In my application, I am doing domain decomposition of a grid, rank=0 (master) contains the entire grid and, the workers (rank>0), subgrids that do the actual work. Now to transfer data from the master to each of the workers, I expose the entire array from the master to all of the workers when creating the MPI Window and the workers do not expose anything. Each worker then simply performs an MPI_Get on the subset of the data it requires. For synchronisation I'm simply using MPI_Win_lock with the SHARED option.

Now the issue is that performance does not scale. What I'm finding is that as the number of workers increases so does the walltime to complete the total data transfers. So my first question is: is there a way for the target (i.e. master process) to service the Get requests in parallel by somehow specifying the number of threads? Or, is that actually forbidden by definition as concurrent access to the same location in memory is not allowed? And therefore my transfers are being serialised?

In writing this, I realise that maybe I should be be doing MPI_Put's explicitly (say via OpenMP) in parallel from the master as the origin. Will this work and be scalable?

Related to this, I also have direct worker-worker transfers for which I'm using MPI_Win_fence, and again I expose all memory to all workers and doing MPI_Get's. As the number of workers increases so does the number of neighbours for each worker but the size of the data transfer per pair decreases. Again, I'm finding constant total transfer time, I've even tried it with PSCW but no real difference in performance. They're pretty well sync'd in terms of when the data transfers happen so maybe that explains that. Again, I wonder if Put's would also be better here but now there will be contention with multiple processes writing to the same process's memory.

This is on Linux using OpenMPI 4.1.1 (MPI-3.1) on a single node (so far, the intention is to scale across many nodes)

Here is some example code:

```
#define NSTEPS 5

/*
 * Entry function
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int infid, wpfid, acfid;
  char *infname, *wpfname;
  int isMaster;
  int err;
  int mpi_rank = 0;
  int mpi_size = 0;
  MPI_Win win = NULL;
  int gsz = 0;
  
  /* Initialise MPI */
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);  // xxx threaded, how?
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_rank);

  isMaster = (mpi_rank == 0);
  
  /* Check input args */
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("\n");
    printf("Usage %s <input file> <win_map>\n", argv[0]);
    printf("\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Cache input file name */
  infname = argv[1];
  wpfname = argv[2];

  if (isMaster) {
    geometry_t geom;
    double *patm;
    double *lons, *lats;
    size_t sz;
    int patm_id, lons_id, lats_id;
    int n, s;
    double *wtimes = d_alloc_1d(mpi_size);
    double *ltimes = d_alloc_1d(mpi_size);
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("========\n");
    printf("EMS sim2\n");
    printf("========\n");
    printf("\n");

    /* Initialise */
    memset(&geom, 0, sizeof(geometry_t));
    
    /* Open input file */
    err = nc_open(infname, NC_NOWRITE, &infid);
    NC_ERR(err);

    /* This is the whole sparse array */
    geom.b2_t = getDimLen(infid, "nMesh2_face");

    /* Global arrays */
    sz = geom.b2_t;
    patm = d_alloc_1d(sz+1);
    lons = d_alloc_1d(sz+1);
    lats = d_alloc_1d(sz+1);

    gsz = (int)sz;
    printf("Master gsz = %d\n", gsz);
    MPI_Bcast(&gsz, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    /* Get the spatial info */
    err = nc_get_var_double(infid, getVarid(infid, "Mesh2_face_x"), lons);
    NC_ERR(err);
    err = nc_get_var_double(infid, getVarid(infid, "Mesh2_face_y"), lats);
    NC_ERR(err);
    
    /* Initialise RMA window */
    err = MPI_Win_create(patm, sz*sizeof(double), sizeof(double),
             MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);
    MPI_ERR(err);

    /* 
     * Simulate steps
     * 
     * In the real application, data would be read out of a netCDF file
     */
    for (s=0; s<NSTEPS; s++) {
      double dt = 1.0;
      
      for (n=1; n<=sz; n++)
    patm[n] = n + s*0.12;

      printf("Master step %d\n", s);

      /* Sync with workers */
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      /* Get timings */
      MPI_Gather(&dt, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, ltimes, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      for (n=1; n<mpi_size; n++)
    wtimes[n] += ltimes[n];
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    printf("\nTiming stats:\n");
    /* Report timing - xxx better to do reduce? */
    for (n=1; n<mpi_size; n++)
      printf("%03d time = %f\n", n, wtimes[n]);
      
  } else {
    /*
     * Worker code
     */
    int nw = mpi_rank;
    geometry_t window;
    size_t start[2], count[2];
    int szS;
    double *lpatm = NULL;
    MPI_Datatype dtype;
    int s, n;
    size_t indexp = nw;
    FILE *f;
    char buf[256];
    
    /* Initialise */
    memset(&window, 0, sizeof(geometry_t));

    /* Open win_map file */
    err = nc_open(wpfname, NC_NOWRITE, &wpfid);
    NC_ERR(err);

    /* get b2_t, wsa info */
    err = nc_get_var1_int(wpfid, getVarid(wpfid, "b2_t_w"),
                &indexp, &window.b2_t);
    NC_ERR(err);
    
    /* Allocate local array for this window */
    szS = window.b2_t;
    lpatm = d_alloc_1d(szS+1);
    window.wsa = i_alloc_1d(szS+1);

    /* Get window local to global array mapping */
    start[0] = nw; start[1] = 1;
    count[0] = 1;  count[1] = szS;
    err = nc_get_vara_int(wpfid, getVarid(wpfid, "wsa"),
                start, count, window.wsa);
    NC_ERR(err);

    MPI_Bcast(&gsz, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("%d:Worker szS = %d\n", mpi_rank, szS);
    /* Reset aux/ghost cells */
    for (n=0; n<szS; n++) {
      if (window.wsa[n] >= gsz) {
    // printf("Ooops! wn=%d, window.wsa[%d]=%d\n", nw, n, window.wsa[n]);
    window.wsa[n] = 1;
      }
    }

    /* Initialise RMA window */
    err = MPI_Win_create(lpatm, szS*sizeof(double), sizeof(double),
             MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);
    MPI_ERR(err);
    
    /* Set up mapping */
    err = MPI_Type_create_indexed_block(szS, 1, window.wsa, MPI_DOUBLE, &dtype);
    MPI_ERR(err);
    err = MPI_Type_commit(&dtype);
    MPI_ERR(err);

    // sleep(5);
    //printf("Worker(%d) ready\n", nw);
    
    /* sleep to simulate loop and barrier */
    for (s=0; s<NSTEPS; s++) {
      double t0, t1, dt;
      
      /* Sync with master */
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      //printf("(%d) before = %f\n", nw, lpatm[10]);

      t0 = MPI_Wtime();
      err = MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_SHARED, 0, 0, win);
      MPI_ERR(err);
      
      err = MPI_Get(lpatm, szS, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, 1, dtype, win);
      MPI_ERR(err);
      
      err = MPI_Win_unlock(0, win);
      MPI_ERR(err);
      t1 = MPI_Wtime();
      dt = t1-t0;
      
      MPI_Gather(&dt, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, NULL, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      
      /* test */
      //      for (n=0; n<szS; n++)
      //printf("(%d) after  = %f\n", nw, lpatm[10]);
    }

  }

  /* Handy for debugging */
  //  sleep(10);
  // MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  MPI_Finalize();

  return(0);
}
```

And if I run it with 2 workers:

```
% mpirun -np 3 ./modelrun tile0b.nc ../compas-mpi/model/tests/setile/tile0_win_map_2W.nc.bak
========
EMS sim2
========
Master gsz = 145230
1:Worker szS = 72606
2:Worker szS = 72624
Master step 0
Master step 1
Master step 2
Master step 3
Master step 4

Timing stats:
001 time = 0.323801
002 time = 0.324102
```

But with 4 workers, it takes longer!

```
% mpirun -np 5 ./modelrun tile0b.nc ../compas-mpi/model/tests/setile/tile0_win_map_4W.nc

========
EMS sim2
========

Master gsz = 145230
2:Worker szS = 36320
4:Worker szS = 36307
1:Worker szS = 36291
3:Worker szS = 36312
Master step 0
Master step 1
Master step 2
Master step 3
Master step 4

Timing stats:
001 time = 0.593371
002 time = 0.556528
003 time = 0.592080
004 time = 0.602115
```

Note: This is still OpenMPI built without UCX or xpmem, so are these timings what you might expect?

Comment: 1. Why are you using RMA? Your application sounds very regular. 2. You are using both passive target synchronization (which allows for worker processes to be not synchronized, which is good) but also active (through the fence). That doesn't make much sense. 3. If you have "many nodes", can your one process still contain the whole grid? 4. Passive target synchronization may take a helper thread, so if you have a bunch of simultaneous Put/Get to one process, they may very well serialize out. Those are just some thoughts I had.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout RMA for master-worker transfers as the workflows are decoupled and I can then overlap transfers and compute very easily via Passive sync. But yes, you're right, the worker-worker RMA is very regular so I'm using RMA because almost all of the documentation says RMA is "better" that some implementations use RDMA for RMA which can greatly improve performance. Yes, one process can easily handle the all the mem on one node.

Comment: I guess I'm still puzzled about the threading support of the MPI library - say I have multiple MPI_Get's to the same process but different mem locations, is there any way to know that the MPI library can handle them in parallel?

Comment: first of all: thanks for the edit. Secondly: nothing in the MPI standard states how threading is done. Usually people combine OpenMP (or some other threading library) with MPI. I'm not aware of any standard way of using multiple threads inside MPI. Like I said: maybe there is only one helper thread for handinglin incoming Puts. And: someone people indeed claim that RMA can work better than regular point-to-point, but I don't believe them. I've certainly never seen it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have now added example code and results